# js jquery ui combo box selection changed event

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm unable to find the proper event for selection changed on a jq-ui combo box, the same as the sample on http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

How can I subscribe to the relevant event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed this:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;

                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
```

to

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;

                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                        self.element.trigger("change",event,{
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
```